# Environment variables are not getting loaded when script is executed on a remote server via SSH (RHEL 8)

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, environment-variables, sshd

I have a vendor script (**startup.sh**) to start application services on a Linux box. Script when called manually by logging into the server (as **sudo su - userID**) initiates all the environment variables. Script has below command line for loading all the variables.

`env > tomcat_envvars.txt`

I have written a new script (ksh) that does an SSH from a master server to all application servers to call the same script (**startup.sh**). Below is the shell script snippet to SSH to each of the application servers and to call the script.

Though the new script is able to start the services, all the environment variables are not getting initialized because of which application jobs are failing.

```
service_status=$(ssh -T <app server name> <<-EOF >/dev/null 2>&1
                <absolute path of startup.sh>
                EOF
                )
```

I suspect the issue could be because of the way I am invoking ssh or it could be something to do with the start-up file (**.bash_profile**) of the user, **userID**.

Please shed some light on the cause of the issue and fix for the same.